# Scribble pad over an image in pyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt4

suppose I want to load an image and scribble on it. But If the image is large then it could not fit into the image viewer. Hence I want a scrollbar. How do I do this?

For example: lets say the image is:

[image]

and when i load it into my program it becomes:

[image]

Now I want to put it into the scrollbar widget(so that the image can be accessed fully) and the most important thing is I want to make any kind of drawing(scribble) on it. How do I do this using PyQt4? Is there any python code available for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to place an image with `QScrollbar` a possible option is to use `QScrollArea`, but if you indicate that you want to draw the correct thing is to use `QGraphicsView` since it allows you to add items. For example to make the scribble you could use `QGraphicsPathItem` and for the image `QGraphicsPixmapItem` as I show below:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class ScribbleView(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ScribbleView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setScene(QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self))
        self._image_item = QtGui.QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        self.scene().addItem(self._image_item)
        self.initial_path()

    def initial_path(self):
        self._path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        pen = QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor("green"), 4, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine, QtCore.Qt.RoundCap)
        self._path_item = self.scene().addPath(self._path, pen)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def load_image(self):
        filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 
            "Open Image", QtCore.QDir.currentPath(), 
            "Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.bmp)")
        if filename:
            self._image_item.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(filename))

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if not self._image_item.pixmap().isNull():
            self._path.moveTo(self.mapToScene(event.pos()))
            self._path_item.setPath(self._path)
        super(ScribbleView, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not self._image_item.pixmap().isNull():
            self._path.lineTo(self.mapToScene(event.pos()))
            self._path_item.setPath(self._path)
        super(ScribbleView, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if not self._image_item.pixmap().isNull():
            self._path.lineTo(self.mapToScene(event.pos()))
            self._path_item.setPath(self._path)       
            self.initial_path()
        super(ScribbleView, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)

class ScribbleWidget(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ScribbleWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        view = ScribbleView()
        self.setCentralWidget(view)
        menubar = self.menuBar()
        file_menu = menubar.addMenu("&File")
        image_action = file_menu.addAction("Load Image")
        image_action.triggered.connect(view.load_image)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = ScribbleWidget()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: @Anjan If my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it then review the [tour], that is the best way to thank.

Comment: One more thing: Suppose In the next step, I want to draw points at random position in this image. so I need to use **self._path.addPolygon(self.mapToScene(x,y,1,1))** function. How do I Use **QtGui.QPainter** in this program so that i can use **drawPoint(x, y)** function?

Comment: @Anjan Why do you want to use QPainter ?, if you want to draw a point use QGraphicsEllipseItem where you can set a QBrush and QPen to set the painting style. The QGraphicsItems are a high level form of "painted", QPainter is something of low level that in this case is not necessary.